# Reducing the input voltage level at the gate terminal of the MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Please refer the below schematic.

I want to use a 30V supply voltage (V1,) but the absolute maximum Vgs of the MOSFET is 20V. There is no significant voltage drop from the supply to the gate in the current design of the schematic. If I use a potential divider circuit, that would increase the rise time of the MOSFET as the charging time of Cgs would increase. How should I solve this? Is there any better approach to this problem instead of potential divider circuit? Do you think there might be a way to achieve this using Zener diodes? If yes, how?

Note: I am trying to switch the gate at 100KHz frequency to obtain the same frequency at the output (R7) with 10% duty cycle. Thus, while designing the gate drive circuit, these timing constraints must be considered.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Zener between GS, or decrease supply voltage of Q10 leg using zener (followers can stay at 30V), or clamp Vgs using signal diode to npn sink regulated to ~16V.

Comment: I assume that C2 and C3 are shown in the wrong place. You currently show a 15V supply, would it be possible just to add a second 15V supply so that it only went to M1 and left Q8 and Q9 still running from 15V? I see another possible problem. During the switching transient, Q8 and Q9 are likely to be on at the same time, however briefly. There is nothing to limit the current they draw.